# Is there way map a working set in MyEclipse to a folder in VSS

Tags: java, version-control, visual-sourcesafe, myeclipse

I have `MyEclipse Workbench 8.6` for developing my project and `Microsoft Visual Sourcesafe (VSS)` as my source version controller. I have too many project in my workspace. I grouping projects by several working set. My question is:

Is there way for map a working set in `MyEclipse` to a folder in `VSS`?

**Edit**

I will show my work space status:
I have four projects with name:

1. `com.sam.api` contains my interfaces.
2. `com.sam.impl.default` contains my default implementation of above project.
3. `com.sam.factory` instantiates an implementation of api.
4. `com.start` is start point of my program.

and I have two `working-set` with names in `MyEclipse`:

1. `sam` is contains three project `com.sam.api`, `com.sam.impl.default`, `com.sam.factory`.
2. `sp` is contains one project `com.start`.

I have following structure in `VSS` :

- `sam-project\sam\com.sam.api`
- `sam-project\sam\com.sam.impl.default`
- `sam-project\sam\com.sam.factory`
- `sam-project\sp\com.start`

Now I have to map four project in `MyEclipse` to four project in `VSS` but I want map two `MyEclipse Working-Set` to two sub-folder `sam` and `sp` in `VSS` but can't do it:(

Comment: do you have any vss plugin's installed on your `MyEclipse` ? Like this: http://vssplugin.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @SreenathSoman Yes, I'm using `VSS` plugin. If don't used it, `MyEclipse` even don't show `VSS` menu.

Comment: on a windows machine ? tried starting eclipse with `-clean` argument ?

Comment: Yes, on `windows xp`. What does `-clean` argumentt?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to both your questions is yes, for any MyEclipse IDE version, based on Eclipse versions upto 3.3

chk this: http://vssplugin.sourceforge.net/

Install the above mentioned plugin onto your MyEclipse. Follow the instructions on the site, on how to share a project (map working set).

I don't think the vssplugin is compatible with your version of MyEclipse.

Steps to map a working set to a folder in VSS

```
Right click on a project in Eclipse, place cursor on Team.

click on Share Project > VSS Configuration Wizard > Next
```

Comment: I don't find any explanation about working set map to vss folder in your page suggestion.

Comment: see the edited answer, can you check which eclipse version is your MyEclipse based on ?

Comment: Yes. `MyEclipse 8.6.1` based on `Eclipse 3.5.2` platform and my `VSS` plugin is `1.6.1`.

Comment: exactly, look at the page in my answer, says it supports upto Eclipse version 3.3. That means, we can't be sure if that plugin would work beyond Eclipse version 3.3.

Comment: Your means is: "I have to rollback to older version of `Eclipse` platform" ?

Comment: Can you follow the steps i put in the answer right now and see if thats working.

Comment: I discuss in original my question that I want share a `MyEclipse Working Set` to a project(folder) in `VSS`.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. You want to map few MyEclipse (folders or project tree or working set) to some folders in VSS right ?

Comment: I sorry for delay in response to your comment. Yes, exactly.

Comment: I test `vss plugin 1.5` but does not  my goals.